# Java Core API Vs Cypher for Neo

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

My question is regarding scaling, speed and what is the best way to use Neo4j Backend with Java.

There are currently 2 options which I have used myself and both seem good enough but I do not know how much would it scale.

1. Java OGM connected to Neo4j Database using Spring. Here I write Cypher queries and use the results. Here I really have to know what I am getting as output from Cypher queries and then I design the output. Paths become hard to parse.
2. Neo4j Java Embedded api where we can use Node, Relationships, Path. Here I can use GraphAlgoFactory which seems like a positive. Also I have more control over the output than the first approach. Nonetheless here I can also use all methods provided by GraphAlgoFactory directly. But I believe all these methods are also available directly via cypher using using apoc

I have gone through this [question1](https://dzone.com/articles/get-full-neo4j-power-using) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28657178/neo4j-traversal-api-vs-cypher) which is 3 years old which gives me an idea but a lot has changed ever since.

1. OGM connected to Neo4j
2. Neo4j Java Embedded api

Comment: Keep in mind that you have a third option which you alluded to: You can use Cypher to interact with the graph, and you can call APOC and Algo procedures from Cypher. If you do need more precise control or speed for some kinds of operations, you can write your own custom procedure, which lets you use the core API so Node, Relationships, and Path are available to you at this level.